# How to get output from Nagios in a file

Tags: linux, nagios

I have configured Nagios monitoring tool for a linux server m/c to monitor another linux host m/c(till now I am monitoring a single m/c only). I have followed the official documentation and installed nagios server on server side and NRPE daemon on client side. As per documentation the nagios is working successfully and maintaining its periodic checks for all the services that I have made it to monitor and also installed some additional plugins too.

But I want to know the procedure how to get output of the monitoring hostory in a particular file in a proper format. As I have not installed the web interface through Apache, yet is there any solution for my problem

Following is the log file I am getting for nagios monitoring:

```
[1349064000] LOG ROTATION: DAILY
[1349064000] LOG VERSION: 2.0
[1349064000] CURRENT HOST STATE: localhost;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.03 ms
[1349064000] CURRENT HOST STATE: remotehost;UP;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.17 ms
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Current Load;OK;HARD;1;OK - load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Current Users;OK;HARD;1;USERS OK - 7 users currently logged in
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;HTTP;OK;HARD;1;HTTP OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK - 1889 bytes in 0.001 seconds
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;PING;OK;HARD;1;PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.04 ms
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Root Partition;CRITICAL;HARD;100;DISK CRITICAL - free space: / 108 MB (1% inode=61%):
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;SSH;OK;HARD;1;SSH OK - OpenSSH_5.1 (protocol 2.0)
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Swap Usage;OK;HARD;1;SWAP OK - 97% free (841 MB out of 870 MB)
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: localhost;Total Processes;OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 79 processes with STATE = RSZDT
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;CPU Load;OK;HARD;1;OK - load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.01
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;Current Users;WARNING;HARD;3;USERS WARNING - 3 users currently logged in
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;File Size;WARNING;HARD;3;WARN: /home/new/ctags.1p has size 13864 Byte. Warn at 13000. :
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;Swap Usage;OK;HARD;1;SWAP OK - 100% free (869 MB out of 870 MB)
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;Total Processes;OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 106 processes
[1349064000] CURRENT SERVICE STATE: remotehost;Zombie Processes;OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 0 processes with STATE = Z
[1349064028] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;remotehost;Current Users;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;USERS WARNING - 3 users currently logged in
[1349064988] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.
[1349065258] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;remotehost;File Size;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;WARN: /home/new/ctags.1p has size 13864 Byte. Warn at 13000. :
[1349065938] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;localhost;Root Partition;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;DISK CRITICAL - free space: / 109 MB (1% inode=61%):
[1349067628] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;remotehost;Current Users;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;USERS WARNING - 3 users currently logged in
[1349068588] Auto-save of retention data completed successfully.
[1349068858] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;remotehost;File Size;WARNING;notify-service-by-email;WARN: /home/new/ctags.1p has size 13864 Byte. Warn at 13000. :
[1349069538] SERVICE NOTIFICATION: nagiosadmin;localhost;Root Partition;CRITICAL;notify-service-by-email;DISK CRITICAL - free space: / 109 MB (1% inode=61%)
```

Tell me please if I am wrong at something regarding this. If any more nagios info is required for this problem, let me know I will share that surely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve, but it's maybe related to status.dat

Comment: I want to achieve all the output in a file with proper timings. As I have specified the periods for checking the services of monitored servers, so I want the output with all the periodic checks nagios is performing with mentioning the time also.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/422433/59925

Answer (score 0):

You can enable more logging by enabling the various log_ options in nagios.cfg, but this is really not what Nagios is for. See the [docs page on nagios.cfg](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html)

The real strength of Nagios is the notification and event handler logic, but if you just want to log the results somewhere, you might also want to look into ndoutils. This will allow you to put the results into a database. Once you get that working, there are other tools than can utilize that data.